# How to store parameter packed function for later called

Tags: c++

I'm building a project with a signal/slot library, and i'd like to be able to execute the slot in a different thread than the signal calling it, like Qt does.

To do that, I'm trying to store a function call with parameter pack to allow varying args number :

```cpp
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

struct SlotProxy {
    template<typename Func, typename ...Args>
    void PostEvent(Func func, Args ... args) {
        _callback = [func, &args...]() {
            func(args...);
        };
    }

    void operator()() {
        _callback();
    }

    std::function<void()> _callback;
};

struct Obj {
    int i{};
    void Print() {
        std::cout << this << " - Obj val : " << i << std::endl;
    }

    void Slot(Obj& obj) {
        obj.Print();
    }
};

void Test(Obj& obj) {
    obj.Print();
}

int main() {
    Obj obj{};
    obj.Print();

    SlotProxy sp{};
    
    // error : no matching call for bind
    auto bind = std::bind(&SlotProxy::PostEvent, &sp, &Test, std::placeholders::_1);

    bind(obj);
}
```

Here `std::bind` gives me an error that it can't find the matching definition, what am I doing wrong?

Subsidary question : How can I bind a member function as a parameter to PostEvent? Does a
nested std::bind would work ?

```cpp
std::bind(&SlotProxy::PostEvent, &p, std::bind(&Obj::Slot, obj, ???), std::placeholders::_1);
```

Comment: With `[func, &args...]`, you capture `args` by reference, **but** as there are been passed by copy, you have dangling reference then.

Comment: Why using `bind` over lambda? `auto bind = [&sp](auto& obj){ sp.PostEvent(&Test, obj); };`?

Comment: Your `SlotProxy` _already_ stores a function call with parameter pack for later invocation (or it will when you fix the dangling reference bug already described). Why do you want to delegate constructing the delegate? Just call `SlotProxy::PostEvent` immediately and call `operator()` later in a different thread.

Comment: The signal/slot lib I'm using takes a callable object of the defined signature to connect a slot, like `signal<void(Obj)>::connect( <callable object of void(Obj) signature> );`. That's why I can't call `SlotProxy::PostEvent` directly, I have to send it to the signal to be later called, but yes it can work with a lambda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem(error) is that `PostEvent` is a member function **template** and when it is used as an argument to `std::bind` as in `&SlotProxy::PostEvent`, the type of its template parameter(s) aren't known.

This means that we need to either use default arguments or explicitly tell the compiler the type of its template parameters. Below is a **contrived example**:

```
template <typename T>
class myclass {
public:
  template<typename U>
  void func(const U&)
  {

  }
};
int main(){

  myclass<int> obj;
  //--------------------------------------------vvvvvv----------->pass the argument explicitly
  auto mylambda = std::bind(&myclass<int>::func<double>, &obj, 5);
  mylambda();

}
```

---

Similarly, you will either need to explicitly pass the template arguments or use default arguments wherever possible.

You should also take care of additional problems that the code might have like dangling references etc.